# Hyperlink and regular text in the same line

Tags: html, node.js, hyperlink, pug

in HTML, it's easy to add hyperlinks to an otherwise constant text flow. This code:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Visit Stack Overflow!</a> It's a great site.
```

produces an output like this:

**[Visit Stack Overflow!](http://stackoverflow.com) It's a great site.**

However, in Jade I've apparantly missed the way of adding regular text after a hyperlink (if there's any), since I can add only paragraphs - this Jade template code:

```
a(href="http://stackoverflow.com") Visit Stack Overflow!
p It's a great site.
```

produces a similar but different output:

[**Visit Stack Overflow!**](http://stackoverflow.com)

**It's a great site.**

So the regular text is in a new line instead of being written after the hyperlink.

Is there any means in Jade to do it the same way as in the HTML example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
p  #[a(href="http://stackoverflow.com") Visit Stack Overflow!] It's a great site.
```

Comment: Sincerely, I don't know Jade, but it looks a code to put nested tags in same line. p "text" #[tag(attr...) "more text" ] "text". If you don't use it, it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.

the `p` tag in the Jade template must be replaced by another combination of letters that has no meaning for Jade.

```
a(href="http://stackoverflow.com") Visit Stack Overflow!
placholder It's a great site.
```

produces the same output as the HTML code in the question.